# Nested for in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested

I have a list and I want to **iterate** over it, and then iterate in a nested `for` insde the first one over the same list from the next position that the first one I've read.

In a language like Java would be:

```
int[10] array;
for (int i=0; i < array.length(); i++)
    for (int j=i+1; j < array.length(); j ++)
        //do something with the array comparing a[i] and a[j]
```

How could I do that on Python?
I try this:

```
for a in array:
     del array[0]
     for a2 in array:
         //do something with the array comparing a and a2
```

But only works in the first iteration.. any help?

Comment: Why do you `del array[0]`? The Java code doesn't remove anything from the array

Answer (score 6):

```
for i in range(0,len(array)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(array)):
        #do something with array[i] and array[j]
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python you use `enumerate` if you want the index while iterating:

```
array = [1,2,3,4]

for index1, value1 in enumerate(array):
    for index2, value2 in enumerate(array[index1+1:]):
        print(index1, index2+index1+1, value1, value2)
```

the `[index1+1:]` slices the array to include only the following items. The output would then be:

```
0 1 1 2
0 2 1 3
0 3 1 4
1 2 2 3
1 3 2 4
2 3 3 4
```

But there is a builtin function that would be a perfect match in your case: [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) which allows you do it even without nested loops:

```
from itertools import combinations

for value1, value2 in combinations(array, 2):
    print(value1, value2)
```

prints:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```